# Change Database structure Sqlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am working on an android application on android studio, and I am using a sqlite database. The thing is, I want to change the structure of it, so do I just have to change it from DB Browser for SQLite, or I need to change it somewhere else ?
Because the code I am working on isn't mine, and I am just starting to lear android developement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option is to change the internal structure of the database file from either DB Browser or command line on your computer and then copy it to your phone's storage when the App is running.

If you don't know the steps:

- Step 1: Create a new database file from either command line or SQLite DB Browser with your required structure.
- Step 2: Place the file in Assest directory in your Project folder. (Assest directory will be in the same folder as the 'res' and 'java' directories are)
- Step 3: On Activity Start event, copy this empty database from Asset directory to your database directory which is generally located at /data/data/your.package/databases

Also you can query ALTER TABLE to add columns (as suggested in comments).

[This explains the syntax for ALTER TABLE](https://sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html). It also explains other methods for implementing Schema Changes.

Comment: *You will have to change the internal structure of the database file from either DB Browser or command line on your computer* ignores the potential to utilise `ALTER TABLE table ADD COLUMN column_definition` which may well be sufficient and simpler to implement.

Comment: Yeah, ALTER is an option but keeping in mind the entry level experience mentioned,  I thought it would be better to let him know how the fresh copy works.